# delete and drag multiple objects of same shape by id

Tags: kineticjs

When two objects of same shape are drawn consecutively, only the latest object drawn could be found with id or name.
eg. I have two circles drawn consecutively and i want to delete them individually on a click of a button.
Scenario : Select one cirlce, click on the delete button and the circle selected should be deleted.
Current result : After selecting a cirlcle and clicking the delete button, only the last drawn circle is getting deleted. Then after selecting another circle, clicking on delete, the circle is not getting deleted.

Similarly, for dragging two objects of same shape, only the last drwan object is getting dragged.

Comment: Show us your code, can't help much without that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you might keep track of the currently selected (draggable) shape and delete it when a button is pressed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Shape Select and Delete Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/kineticjs/5.0.6/kinetic.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var activeShape,
                size = window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight / 3 : window.innerWidth / 3,
                strokeWidth = size / 8,
                layer = new Kinetic.Layer,
                stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                    width: window.innerWidth,
                    height: window.innerHeight,
                    container: 'container'
                }),
                circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
                    x: strokeWidth + ( size / 2 ),
                    y: strokeWidth + ( size / 2 ),
                    width: size,
                    height: size,
                    fill: 'red',
                    strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
                    draggable: true
                }),
                rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
                    x: strokeWidth,
                    y: strokeWidth + circle.y() + circle.radius(),
                    width: size,
                    height: size,
                    fill: 'red',
                    strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
                    draggable: true
                }),
                text = new Kinetic.Text({
                    x: rect.width() * 1.3,
                    y: rect.height(),
                    text: 'Delete',
                    fill: 'red',
                    fontSize: size / 2,
                    stroke: 'black',
                    strokeWidth: size / 64
                });

            layer.add( circle );
            layer.add( rect );
            layer.add( text );

            stage.add( layer );

            focusShape( circle );
            focusShape( rect );

            layer.draw();

            text.on( 'click', function() {
                if ( activeShape ){
                    activeShape.destroy();
                    activeShape = null;

                    layer.draw();
                }
            });

            function focusShape( shape ){
                shape.on( 'mousedown', function() {
                    if ( activeShape )
                        activeShape.stroke( null );

                    this.stroke( 'black' );

                    activeShape = this;

                    layer.draw();
                })
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nidor)